# How to let ansible to run sudo only once for multiple tasks requiring sudo?

Tags: ansible, sudo

When ansible runs multiple tasks as root (become: yes, become_method: sudo), I found that it runs each task in separate sessions:

```
john.doe    481901  481809  0 19:44 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/sh -c sudo -H -S  -p "[sudo via ansible, key=blabla1] password:" -u root /bin/sh -c 'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-blabla1 ; /usr/bin/python3 /home/john.doe/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1609789454.667826-84063-275493394187528/AnsiballZ_command.py' && sleep 0

john.doe    481937  481809  0 19:44 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/sh -c sudo -H -S  -p "[sudo via ansible, key=blabla2] password:" -u root /bin/sh -c 'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-blabla2 ; /usr/bin/python3 /home/john.doe/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1609789496.208312-84094-182235695212206/AnsiballZ_command.py' && sleep 0
```

and as a result of this, it does not use sudo cache
(/var/run/sudo/ts/john.doe) but to authenticate each time. It is
not an issue if you only use password authentication because you
specify the password once using `--ask-become-pass`, however when I
used [Duo Mobile](https://duo.com/) as a second factor to authenticate, it pushes each
time when sudo is authenticated. So if you have multiple hosts and multiple tasks, you have to constantly answer the push, and when push is delayed when there is a "denial attack", ansible run will fail.

My questions:

1. Is there a way to let ansible to sudo once, and then run
   multiple tasks? Using the above example, it can and should run
   each of the `AnsiballZ_command.py` files after a single sudo
   authentication.
2. Is there another to prevent the Duo Mobile paging?

Comment: Use duo mobile to connect to a machine inside your network from where you will run your ansible scriipts not needing a second factor auth. Else you need a way to bypass that second auth (like this is done on e.g. gitlab, google-api.... with a token).

Comment: @Zeitounator The requirement is to use second auth for sudo regardless the user comes from inside or outside, I just don't want to use authentication for every task.

Comment: Let's suppose we can acheive this (which I"m pretty much sure is not possible....) and that you can now schedule your script in tower/awx to run at 4am. You will still get at least one push. And there goes away your automation.(unless you like to tap on you phone in the middle of the night)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no answer for the question. The three workarounds are:

1. At the beginning of the ansible task, disable sudo password:

```
perl -i -pe 's/(?<=\s)PASSWD/NOPASSWD/' /etc/sudoers.d/$(who am i | sed "s/\./-/; s/ .*//")
```

and at the end, enabled it (swap the PASSWD and NOPASSWD in above code).

2. At the beginning of the run, disable the Duo authentication at the
   duo console (manually or with API call), and at the end re-enable
   it.
3. Setup an ansible user without Duo authentication, but this is less
   secure as compared with #2, but still a workaround if your security
   requirement allows it.

PS: You can use ssh keys to authenticate sudo, see [this link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pamsshagentauth/).